# Support for SBS left/right videos with Google VR SDK

Tags: android, google-vr, stereoscopy, google-vr-sdk

I have some side-by-side left/right videos (in mp4 format) and my employer wants me to make an app that use the Google VR SDK to play videos for CardBoard users.

Can the Google VR SDK play these videos (without anything to do my self for the rendering) by taking the left side of the video for the left eye and the right side of the video for the right side?

I see that there's a `VrVideoView` class that has a `loadVideo` method that takes a `VrVideoView.Option`. In these options, there's a `TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER`.

In order to be clear my questions are:

- Has the Google VR SDK a viewer that can play SBS Left/Right video ?
- If not, has the Google VR SDK a viewer that can play a SBS Over/Under video?
- If yes, should i say my employer "instead of doing SBS left/right videos, you should do SBS Over/Under videos in mp4 format because they are directly handled by the Google VR SDK" ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the you want to play a 360° stereoscopic over/under video, the VrVideoView can play it.

If you want to play normal stereoscopic videos, you have to manage the rendering by yourself and take the good part of the video each time you do the renderring for an eye.

Quick and dirty example :

https://github.com/Zanfas/Cardboard_VideoPlayer